# Rounding decimal in a table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know if its possible to ask a question here, that i really dont have a clue how to fix

How do i round all numbers in this table to only show 1 decimal with jquery ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>2012</th>
    <th>2013</th>
    <th>2014</th>
    <th>2015</th>
    <th>2016</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.53</td>
    <td>2.56</td>
    <td>7.45</td>
    <td>54.32</td>
    <td>2.534</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54.43</td>
    <td>26.24</td>
    <td>33.65</td>
    <td>33.65</td>
    <td>2.53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>33.56</td>
    <td>46.23</td>
    <td>33.65</td>
    <td>24.76</td>
    <td>3.65</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just round the decimals to 1 decimal

Comment: <pre><code><table>
      <tr>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2013</th>
        <th>2014</th>
        <th>2015</th>
        <th>2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2.5</td>
        <td>2.6</td>
        <td>7.4</td>
        <td>54.3</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>54.4</td>
        <td>26.2</td>
        <td>33.6</td>
        <td>33.6</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>33.6</td>
        <td>46.2</td>
        <td>33.6</td>
        <td>24.8</td>
        <td>3.6</td>
      </tr>
    </table></pre></code>

Comment: Yes, I want to rounding to 1 decimal

Answer (score 1):

Replace *comma* with `.` and use `toFixed(1)`

```
$( "td" ).each( function(){
  var value = $(this).text();
  value = Number(value.replace(/,/, "." )).toFixed(1);
  $(this).text( value );
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$( "td" ).each( function(){
  var value = $(this).text();
  value = Number(value.replace(/,/, "." )).toFixed(1);
  $(this).text( value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>2012</th>
    <th>2013</th>
    <th>2014</th>
    <th>2015</th>
    <th>2016</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2,53</td>
    <td>2,56</td>
    <td>7,45</td>
    <td>54,32</td>
    <td>2,534</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54,43</td>
    <td>26,24</td>
    <td>33,65</td>
    <td>33,65</td>
    <td>2,53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>33,56</td>
    <td>46,23</td>
    <td>33,65</td>
    <td>24,76</td>
    <td>3,65</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**

Since you only have the decimal now, so just use `toFixed(1)` after converting the value to number

```
$( "td" ).each( function(){
  var value = $(this).text();
  value = Number(value).toFixed(1);
  $(this).text( value );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("td").map(function(){
   $(this).text(Number.parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>2012</th>
    <th>2013</th>
    <th>2014</th>
    <th>2015</th>
    <th>2016</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.53</td>
    <td>2.56</td>
    <td>7.45</td>
    <td>54.32</td>
    <td>2.534</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54.43</td>
    <td>26.24</td>
    <td>33.65</td>
    <td>33.65</td>
    <td>2.53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>33.56</td>
    <td>46.23</td>
    <td>33.65</td>
    <td>24.76</td>
    <td>3.65</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct to understand your question for rounding to 1 decimal do like below example:

```js
    var num = 54.5678;
    var n = num.toFixed(1);
    alert(n);
```

Above code will generate 54.6 you can do like this in your code.

Comment: Yes that the way I want.
But how do you do that with the whole table?